# Start android activity from receiver (inside running service)

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to display an alert when a sms is received, so my idea is to start a new activity that launch the alertdialog.

My service starts with no problem, and starts receiver as well..

I can receive sms and display toast alerts fine.. but i'd like to show a custom alertdialog instead.

This is the activity that starts my service (ServiceExampleActivity ):

```
public class ServiceExampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btnStartService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        Button btnStopService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

        btnStartService.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                StartMyService();
            }
        });

        btnStopService.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                StopMyService();
            }
        });          

    }

    private void StartMyService() {
        Intent myServiceIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceTest.class);
        startService(myServiceIntent);
    }

    private void StopMyService() {
        Intent myServiceIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceTest.class);
        stopService(myServiceIntent);
    }        
}
```

This is my Service (ServiceTest):

```
public class ServiceTest extends Service {

    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
        theFilter.addAction(ACTION);

        this.myBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                StartDialogActivity(context, intent);

            }
        };

        this.registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, theFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        Log.d("ServiceTest", "Started");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started...", 3000).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", 3000).show();
    }

    private void StartDialogActivity(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent dlgIntent = new Intent(context, DialogActivity.class);               
        dlgIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);      
        context.startActivity(dlgIntent);   
    }
}
```

And this is the activity i want to launch to display the alertdialog normally..

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);       

    }
}
```

When it tries to start the activity, the app crashes..
Can you tell me were is the error..??

Comment: I wouldn't try to show a toast in `onDestroy()` At that point your service is pretty much dead. Otherwise I don't see anything wrong with this code. Did you look in the logcat? Are you sure there are no errors? Turn off the filtering of your logcat so you can also see system error messages. Post what you find in the logcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, you want start activity from service

```
Intent dlgIntent = new Intent(context, DialogActivity.class);
dlgIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(dlgIntent );
```

Comment: the emulator just says "application in process(...) is not responding", can you try my code please??

Comment: your solution is correct!!!! my mistake was that i did'nt register DialogActivity class inside the Manifest.xml file... thank you!!!